# How to share API keys throughout Java project

Tags: java, oop, parse-platform

I am writing a Java library that will allow a user to interact with the Parse database through its REST API. In order to send each request, each request header must include two API keys specific to the user's given project. My hope is the user can initialize a Parse class one time only with both of these keys, so that each time the user is required to send a request to the REST API, these operation classes (which configure and send the requests and vary based on whether the operation is save, update, query, etc.) can easily access these keys and add them to their request.

I am trying to initialize the user-facing Parse class like so:

```
Parse parseDB = new Parse("API id1", "API id2");
```

The rest of the time however, the user should just be able to interact with ParseObjects, and when calling save or other operations on these objects have the ParseObject instances create a Parse Command class instance that takes care of actually making the request, like so:

```
ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("classname");
obj.save();
//this will create an instance of a ParseCommand class, which will actually send the request
```

I'm not sure if this is good OO design or not, and while I'm fairly sure there's a better way to do it, I have no idea how these ParseCommand Classes should be accessing these two API keys after the first initialization of the Parse object. If anyone has any suggestions on best practice on how to be accessing these keys, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Perhaps make the API key a static variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Moshe for suggesting static variables, I did not think of that and while I know static variables are not considered good style in OOP, it worked perfectly for me. I ended up declaring two static variables in my Parse class, and in each ParseCommand class, I just accessed each API key though Parse.APIKey1 and Parse.APIKEy2. A simple solution, but in my case, this works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring , you can dependency inject the Parse property into the ParseObject. The injected Parse type property can be made singleton and also you can inject the api keys via constructor injection to the Parse bean. Your API keys can be taken out from the code and configured in spring xml in that way. Below snippet will you an idea.

```
<bean id="parseObj" class="com.parse.ParseObject">
      <property name="parseDB" ref="parse"/>
</bean>



  <bean id="parse" class="com.parse.ParseDB" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="API-KEY1"/>
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="API-KEY2"/>
        </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

[A simple dependency injection example here](http://simplespringtutorial.com/di.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am currently using Moshe's static variable suggestion out of ease of implementation, but I will definitely be trying this out sooner than later!